# how to simulate Post in a form in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, curl, http-post

In [this site](http://www.chronodrive.com/prehome.searchshop.searchshoplayercontent.goshop.actionlink/1076/Prehome$007c1042_Orl$00e9ans$007csearch$0020results), i want to add a product to basket,

i monitored the network by [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/), i want to simulate this request by a form,  and i try this:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $codeHtml .= "<form id='monForm' action='http://www.chronodrive.com/home.componentark.productslist.productthumbnail.favoriteandbasket.emptyadditem:send-analytics/LV0000007704/-1/CLASSIC/-1/WEB$007cPUSH_HOME$007c1$002f12745162/Homepage$007cArk$007cadd$0020to$0020cart$002fLV0000007704$002fEau$0020min$00e9rale$0020naturelle' method='post' target='iframe' style='display:none;'>";
        $codeHtml .=    "<input name=\"t:zoneid\"  value='dummy'/>";

        $codeHtml .=    "<input id=\"submit".$i."\" type=\"submit\">";
        $codeHtml .= '</form>'."\n";
    }
```

**UPDATE**

i tried by **CURL**, by it didn't add any article

**UPDATE2**

When in inspect the network, post parameter that i need for this request is :

```
t:zoneid=dummy
```

and the URL is:

```
http://www.chronodrive.com/home.componentark.productslist.productthumbnail.favoriteandbasket.emptyadditem:send-analytics/LV0000007704/-1/CLASSIC/-1/WEB$007cPUSH_HOME$007c1$002f12745162/Homepage$007cArk$007cadd$0020to$0020cart$002fLV0000007704$002fEau$0020min$00e9rale$0020naturelle
```

there isn't another parameter

Comment: Can you show us your curl attempt? cURL is the correct method, something must have been not quite right.

Comment: @ZBerg i tried in Postman, but i need to do this with a form, i tried curl for seeing if i monitored correctly or not

Comment: Okay, so to be clear, you want to simulate a post, but by manually pressing the button? If so, you need to pay close attention to the page and emulate each field used within the form.

Comment: I did have a look at the site in question, theirs alot of javascript in play, This maywell need some debugging before you dive right in. Try diverting the page request to yourself, and capturing all $_POST and $_GET variables to see what your up against.

Comment: @ZBerg There is just one POST when you add a product to basket. i put the URL in action and there is just one Parameter "dummy"

Comment: Okay, rather than firebug, ive just used chromes and firefoxs own network inspector to do just as you said. Add an item while monitoring network, you can then right click and choose "copy as curl". Doing this shows you all of the data posted, adapt and import this data to your own form.

Comment: I will add, the data delivered appears to contain some tokenised data that may or may not need extracting from the html and including in your post... I have seen this before with many login curl operations i have performed.

Comment: @ZBerg thanks for your answer, but i know how use firebug or other network inspector for using CURL, but i need to simulate this request via a FORM, and when you inspect the network, there is just one parameter to send, did you arrive to simulate via a FORM?

Comment: You try we try, i provided some advice in the direction of an answer.... "i want to simulate this request by a form", extracting data from an example request and including it in your form, is simulating it. Can you be clearer if that is not your requirement? Thankyou

Comment: @ZBerg i edited my Post !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123658/discussion-between-zberg-and-parik).

Comment: Tried to catch you in chat -> I have a few more questions, Is the website yours, and you are trying to add a new feature, or is the website external and you are trying todo this remotely? Ive had a much better look at the website, if the website is only seeking the post value you mention and you have the correct url it should work. The fact that it is not working indicates they may have additional requirements; a paired session, ajax handshake, referer checking etc